# win32_powerplan does'nt work on windows server 2008

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I have some wmi scripts which collect the server information, one among which is the windows power plan info.

I have used the following query

"SELECT ElementName,InstanceID,ISActive FROM win32_powerplan"

it works well againts win2k8 R2 and above but it failed when i ran it against win2k8.

according to thishttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd904531(v=vs.85).aspx it seems minimum requirement for win32_powerplan class to work is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Is there any other (wmi) way to get power plan info on a win2k8 server

Answer (score 1):

If the [`Win32_PowerPlan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd904531%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class is not available, you can use the [`Power Scheme Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372711%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) WinApi functions. Try the [`PowerEnumerate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.